# Gradle android cannot find symbol Context

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I have a java + kotlin android project that builds and runs fine in Android Studio. I am now setting up CI and need to run Gradle from the terminal.
But when I run `./gradlew :app:lint` I get a lot of errors like this:

```
symbol:   class Context
location: class ConnectivityMonitor
e: /*******/LocalAppHistory.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
public boolean hasSeenOnboarding(Context context) {
                                 ^
```

I get the same type of error for `Context, CognitoUserSession, Typeface, CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider...` and many more.
It only applies to the `app` project and none of the other modules.

#### The `app` `gradle.build` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 27
   buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "****"
       minSdkVersion 21
       targetSdkVersion 27
       versionCode 48
       versionName "1.3.0-dev"
       testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       renderscriptTargetApi 18
       renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
       multiDexEnabled true
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
       }
   }

   testOptions {
       unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
   }
}

dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   implementation project(':corentiumio')
   implementation project(':uicomponents')
   implementation project(':core')
   implementation project(':localrepo')
   implementation project(':cloudio')
   implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
       transitive = true
   }
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
   implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.4.2'
   implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.22'
   implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.2.22'
   implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.4.2'
   implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.4.2'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
   implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'

   testImplementation 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.13.0'
   testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.5.1'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
   androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
   })
   androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5') {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support'
   }
   androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test:rules:0.5') {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support'
   }
   androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2') {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, once I got this error while switching git branch from Kotlin Compiler that can't find symbols.

I did clear cache then it worked,

```
rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/
```

Seems while switching branch previous branch files cached created this issue.

Give a try if you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. I did forget to mention that I get the same error on the CI server also.